# How to prevent first flex item from collapsing while having the last item take the remaining space

Tags: html, css

I'm building a one line input control that mixes user edited text and non-editable blocks. I want to make easy for user to click on the first or last editable item and have the browser put focus into the element. For that, I need to set `min-width:5px` for the first item and `width:100%` for the last item [like this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-l61fzq?file=style.css):

```
<div class="app">
  <div class="el1" contenteditable="true">should not collapse</div>
  <div class="el2">block</div>
  <div class="el3" contenteditable="true">should take 100% width</div>
</div>

.app { display: flex; }
.el1 { min-width: 5px; }
.el3 { width: 100%; }
.el2 { background-color: aquamarine; padding: 5px; }
```

However, the first time collapses on white-space. I've tried both `flex-wrap: nowrap;` on `.app` and `white-space: nowrap;` on `.el1`, but it doesn't give me the desired result.

**Updates**

It seems to be enough to set `flex-shrink:0` for the `.el1` as by default it's set to `flex-shrink:1` and so as I understand it allows collapsing. But I'm not sure that's the way to go. Anyone can confirm?

Answer (score 1):

Try to give the first collapsing box the following style

```
.el1 {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

And it will not collapse anymore and it will take its text width.

Comment: I can't use `130px` because I want it to grow as I type in text

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong , you want when user clicks on the editable input then this input takes all the width, right?

Comment: first input or the last input? For the first input I want to take as much space as required based on the text content inside, for the last input I want to take the remaining space

Comment: I get your inquiry now.
Then give your first box style the following property ```flex: 0 0 auto;```. I updated the answer and i wish it solves your question.

Comment: so why setting `flex: 0 0 auto;` can help?

Comment: **Flex** property is shorthand for three properties in order and they're flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis, we change flex-basis which specifies the initial length of a flexible item and the third property to be auto, you can discover it more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

Comment: Yeah, I know :) Well, it seems to be enough to set `flex-shrink:0` as by default it's `flex-shrink:1` to achieve what I want. Your answer prompted me to experiment, so thanks, upvoted it! I'll add my findings to the question body, maybe somebody will provide an elaborate explanation of the behavior

Comment: Exactly , glad to help.